# Pinch Media - Core Location Optional

Tags: iphone, objective-c, statistics

Will using PinchMedia and including Core Location frameworks make it unusable on the iPod Touch which doesn't have GPS? If so, is there a way to minimize this dependency since my actual application doesn't care? It would be nice to see, but basically I'm trying to use it to provide feedback from users on things they'd like to see improved or added, or corner cases where my unittests didn't capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Location exists on the iPod touch also - it falls back on WiFi to do location if there is no GPS

That said, your users may find it odd as your app will ask for their location for no apparent reason, if it has nothing to do with your app. I would personally find that a good enough reason to ditch an app.

Comment: Yah, that's a good point. I'll probably disable its use of Core Location then since it's more of a statistical curiosity. The bug and application feedback are much more important for my quality control needs.